# Is there another solution to find the maximum repetition of the key combination in Kafka Topic using Kafka Streams API?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to aggregate the maximum value in the given topic.
In fact, I did it, but it wasn't the best solution according to me. Before I started to explain my problem deeply, I want to demonstrate used entities.

Our producer API gives to the Streams API JSON objects(InputAction) as shown below.

Key-Value pair
The key point out the ***eventId***.
The value points out the eventId, marketId, and outcomeNo. You can see the sample input below.

```
{
  "eventId": 213, //Integer
  "marketId": 12, //Integer
  "outcomeNo": 3, //Integer
}
```

If I have to explain, logically every event has different markets and each market has a different outcome and their Ids.

Here is the Apache-Kafka-Streams API java implementation;

The main processor in the Streams API consumes to ***events*** topic.

```
StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder();
        KStream<String,InputAction> sourceTopic = streamsBuilder.stream(AppConfigs.topicName,
                Consumed.with(AppSerdes.String(),AppSerdes.InputAction()));
```

After consuming the source topic, I'm generating a key with 3 fields. Because of that's 3 field combination is a unique value for my business logic and I must aggregate the count and find the maximum value for each event.

Here is the first aggregation;

Hint: MarketAggregates Pojo includes;
EventId, MarketId, OutcomeNo, and Count.

```
   KStream<String,MarketAggregates> firstAgg =  sourceTopic.selectKey((k,v) -> v.getEventId().toString() + "-" + v.getMarketId().toString() + "-" + v.getOutcomeNo().toString())
    .groupByKey(Grouped.with(AppSerdes.String(),AppSerdes.InputAction()))
            .aggregate(
                    //Init
                    () -> new MarketAggregates()
                            .withEventId(0)
                            .withMarketId(0)
                            .withOutcomeNo(0)
                            .withCount(0),
                    //Adder
                    (key, value, aggValue) -> new MarketAggregates()
                            .withCount(aggValue.getCount() + 1)
                            .withEventId(value.getEventId())
                            .withOutcomeNo(value.getOutcomeNo())
                            .withMarketId(value.getMarketId()),
                    //Serializer
                    Materialized.<String,MarketAggregates, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(
                            AppConfigs.stateStoreName).withValueSerde(AppSerdes.MarketAggregates())
            ).toStream();
```

As you see above, I had to find the count of the combination per event and find out a KStream for finding the maximum count of each event. (*I'm suspect exactly this point. Have you any of the better choices?*)

Hence, as I said, here is my extra effort to find out the maximum count of the combination.

```
    var secondAgg = firstAgg.groupBy((k,v) -> v.getEventId(),Grouped.with(AppSerdes.Integer(),AppSerdes.MarketAggregates()))
            .reduce(new Reducer<MarketAggregates>() {
                @Override
                public MarketAggregates apply(MarketAggregates marketAggregates, MarketAggregates v1) {
                    if(v1.getCount() > marketAggregates.getCount())return  v1;
                    if(marketAggregates.getCount() > v1.getCount()) return  marketAggregates;

                    return marketAggregates;
                }
            }).toStream();
```

Btw, I know Kafka Streams API doesn't give us such as sort(), avg(), max(), etc. methods cause each data can come to another partition on the different machines. But I feel has a better way than mine.

However, I want to get data from Streams API per minute. That's why I implemented windowedBy and finally pushed the result, which is the eventId-Result pair, to the result topic for consumer API.

In this case, Result POJO will be the winner of the eventId-marketId-outcomeNo combination which has the maximum count in real-time.

```
    secondAgg.groupBy((k,v) -> v.getEventId(),Grouped.with(AppSerdes.Integer(),AppSerdes.MarketAggregates()))
          .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(1)))
          .aggregate(
                  //Init
                  () -> new Result()
                  .withEventId(0).withMarketId(0).withOutcomeNo(0),
                  //Adder
                  (key,value,aggValue) -> new Result()
                  .withOutcomeNo(value.getOutcomeNo())
                  .withEventId(value.getEventId())
                  .withMarketId(value.getMarketId()),
                  //Serializer
                  Materialized.<Integer,Result, WindowStore<Bytes,byte[]>>as(
                          AppConfigs.stateStoreName2
                  ).withValueSerde(AppSerdes.Result())
          ).toStream().to(AppConfigs.resultTopic);


    KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(streamsBuilder.build(),props);
    streams.start();
```